# Correct way of reconnecting to the socket after ECONNRESET (Nodejs net.Socket)

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am using the native Nodejs `net` module for establishing socket connection to a hardware device over LAN.
I have implemented some event handlers, for example, I am listening to `data` event, and everything works as expected!

```js
const net = require('net');
let reader = new net.Socket();

reader.connect(READER_PORT, READER_IP);

// Some event handlers, working perfectly fine...
reader.on('data', (data) => {
    // Process the data           
});

reader.on('close', (error) => {
   // Reconnect here
});
```

However, when I am not using the connection for about 5-10 minutes (it staying idle), it is automatically closing itself, and it is emitting the `close` event with the following error:

```
read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:208:20) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

I want to re-establish the connection when I am getting the `close` or `error` event.
I have tried to use the `reader.connect()` as I initially did above when I caught those events.
However, I am not receiving any `data` from the socket after this, i.e. `data` handlers are never called.

What is the correct way of reconnecting to the socket in this case?

Comment: sockets close after some period of time if idle, try: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you, sir, it solved my problem! Please consider adding this as an answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned by @Lawrence Cherone, sockets close after some period of time if idle.
To solve this, the TCP keep-alive needs to be enabled.

For Node.js (the `net` module) it can be enabled using `socket.setKeepAlive()` method (https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay).
And it solved my problem.

**UPDATE 2021**

I have written everything in detail about it in my article:
https://abdullaev.dev/how-to-integrate-nodejs-with-uhf-rfid-reader/